# Get public and private key from ASN1 encrypted pem certificate

Tags: java, security, ssl, encryption, asn.1

I am trying to sign a particular string with private key which i will get from a pem certificate. This certificate is encrypted with a pass phrase. Format of certificate (.pem file) is something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,A60C80692F0FEB16

Fq/awhS....
+..
+..
+..
+..
+....detSug=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Code that i wrote to fetch public and private key from this certificate is :

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Generator;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMDecryptorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMEncryptedKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;


import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

class MainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
        PrivateKey pk = readPrivateKey("C:/Input/CERT.pem","passphrase");
        PublicKey pubk = readPublicKey("C:/Input/CERT.pem","passphrase");
        byte[] data = "ABCEFG20150520163306".getBytes("UTF8");

        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
        sig.initSign(pk);
        sig.update(data);
        byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
        System.out.println("Singature:" + new BASE64Encoder().encode(signatureBytes));

        sig.initVerify(pubk);
        sig.update(data);
        System.out.println(sig.verify(signatureBytes));

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private static PrivateKey readPrivateKey(String privateKeyPath, String keyPassword) throws IOException {

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(privateKeyPath);

        PEMParser keyReader = new PEMParser(fileReader);

        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
        PEMDecryptorProvider decryptionProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(keyPassword.toCharArray());
        System.out.println(keyReader.getClass());
        Object keyPair = keyReader.readObject();
        PrivateKeyInfo keyInfo;
        System.out.println(keyPair.getClass());


        if (keyPair instanceof PrivateKeyInfo) {
            System.out.println("Correct instance found");

            PEMKeyPair decryptedKeyPair = ((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) keyPair).decryptKeyPair(decryptionProv);
            keyInfo = decryptedKeyPair.getPrivateKeyInfo();
        } else {
            keyInfo = ((PEMKeyPair) keyPair).getPrivateKeyInfo();
        }

        keyReader.close();

        return converter.getPrivateKey(keyInfo);
    }


    private static PublicKey readPublicKey(String privateKeyPath, String keyPassword) throws IOException {

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(privateKeyPath);
        PEMParser keyReader = new PEMParser(fileReader);

        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
        PEMDecryptorProvider decryptionProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(keyPassword.toCharArray());

        Object keyPair = keyReader.readObject();
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo keyInfo;

        if (keyPair instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
            PEMKeyPair decryptedKeyPair = ((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) keyPair).decryptKeyPair(decryptionProv);
            keyInfo = decryptedKeyPair.getPublicKeyInfo();
        } else {
            keyInfo = ((PEMKeyPair) keyPair).getPublicKeyInfo();
        }
        keyReader.close();
        return converter.getPublicKey(keyInfo);
    }
}
```

This code is working fine, but now i have to do the same thing for an ASN1 certificate which looks like this

```
Bag Attributes
localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
friendlyName: le-d5391255-2e94-48fe-8327-caca5d9aa498<Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Key Attributes
X509v3 Key Usage: 10 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBA....
+..
+..
+..
+..
+....N5kNrDV0Yg==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Bag Attributes
localKeyID: 00 01 00 00 
1.3.6.1.4.1.322.17.3.92: 00 08 00 00 
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.20: 15 0D 78 6A D0 18 CB A2 D1 7F D1 C2 B2 7A E0 53 70 D7 ED F9 
1.3.6.1.4.1.313.17.3.79: 46 00 61 00 9E 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 2D 00 50 00 43 00 00 00 
subject=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA1 (Server)/OU=ABC-XYZ Private Limited/CN=QICERT
issuer=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE5DCCA8yg....
+..
+..
+..
+..
+....Y7LF
Byuyq1Pe4QY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Bag Attributes
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.92: 00 08 00 00 
1.3.1.1.4.1.221.17.3.20: 1D 44 89 B2 45 26 7F 3F 6B 92 C5 3A 7B 72 63 CA D2 70 2A DD 
subject=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA1
issuer=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIESTCCAzGgAwI....
+..
+..
+..
+..
+....Y7LF
iY44mB2Sev4/02GkW7
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When i run this code for this new certificate, i get following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMEncryptedKeyPair
    at MainClass.readPrivateKey(MainClass.java:92)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:47)
```

Based on this error message, I am trying to change my code to get private-public key pair for ASN1 type but I am not able to do so.

I am using [this](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse461/14wi/projects/proj4/natfiles/ParserTest.java) and [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo)  as a reference.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the public key for signing.

Comment: yes you are right, signing is done with private key only but verification can be done with public key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of help from colleague/batch-mates, I was finally able to solve this problem. This is what i did:
First i converted the pem certificate into a der certificate by using following command

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -passin pass:passphrase -in "C:\Input\CERT.pem" -out "C:\Input\CERT.der"-nocrypt
```

Then I used following class to sign and encode a give string based on certificate received above:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

class MainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            MessageDigest cript = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            cript.reset();
                    cript.update(args[0].getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    byte[] b_digest = cript.digest();

            Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            PrivateKey pk = get("C:/Input/CERT.der");
            sign.initSign(pk);
            sign.update(b_digest);
            byte[] b1 = sign.sign();

            String signedString = new String(b1);
            String s2 = new String(Base64.encode(b1));

            System.out.println("_______________PrivateKey_________________________");
            System.out.println(pk.toString() +"|");
            System.out.println("_______________Digest_________________________");
            String temp = new String(b_digest);
            System.out.println(temp + "|");
            System.out.println("_______________Signature_________________________");
            System.out.println(signedString +"|");
            System.out.println("_______________Encoded_________________________");
            System.out.println(s2 +"|");

            }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public static PrivateKey get(String filename) throws Exception {
        File f = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        dis.readFully(keyBytes);
        dis.close();

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }
}
```

All this class does is takes the string to be signed as input form command line and signs it using certificate provided as input.

Hope all those who encounter something similar to what i did can pull some help out of this.
Thanks!